# Formal UML representation of reshaping a data frame

Tags: uml, structure, class-diagram

For documentation of the restructuring of a data table from "wide" using a *criteria* column for each score to using a `score` column and a `criterion` column my first reaction was to use UML class diagram.

[image: Wide and long versions of the same class / data table]

I am aware that by changing the structure of the data table, the class attributes have not changed.

**My first question** is whether the wide or the long version is the more correct representation of the data table?

**My second question** is whether it would make sense to relate the two representations - and if so, by which relationship?

**My third question** would be whether something else than a UML class diagram would be more suitable for documenting the reshaping (data preprocessing before showing distribution as a box pot in R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You jumped a little bit to fast from the table to the UML.  This makes your question very confusing, because what is wide as a table is represented long as a class, and the contrary.

Reformulating your problem, it appears that you are refactoring some tables.  The wide table shows several values for a same student in the same row.  This means that the maximum number of exercises is fixed by the table structure:

```
ID    Ex1  Ex2  Ex3 .... Ex N 
-----------------------------
111    A    A   A   ...   A
119    A    C   -   ...   D
127    B    F   B   ...   F
```

The long table has fewer columns, and each row shows only 1 specific score of 1 specific student:

```
ID   #    Score 
---------------
111  1     A 
111  2     A
111  3     A   
          ...
111  N     A
119  1     A
119  2     C
          ...
```

You can model this structure in an UML class diagram. But in UML, the table layout doesn't matter:  that's an issue of the ORM mapping and  you could perfectly have one class model (with an attribute or an association having a multiplicity `1..N`) that could be implemented using either the wide or the long version.  If the multiplicity would be `1..*`  only the long option would work.

Now to your questions:

1. Both representations are correct; they just have different characteristics.  The wide is inflexible, since the maximum number of scores is fixed by the table structure.  Also adding a new score requires in fact to update a record (so the possible concurrency of both models is not the same).  The long is a little more complex to use if you want to show history of a student scores in a row.
2. Yes it makes sense to relate both, especially if you're writing for a transformation of the first into the second.
3. UML would not add necessarily value here. If you're really about tables and values, you could as well use an Entity/Relationship diagram. But UML has the advantage of [allowing database modelling](https://www.eetimes.com/database-modeling-in-uml/) as well and it lets you add behavioral aspects. If not now, then later.  You could consider using the non-standard [`«table»` stereotype](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html#TablesEntitiesViews), to clarify what you are modelling a table (so a low level view on your design).

Comment: Useful also to get the pointer to [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). This answer provides me the clarity, I need to understand UML and improve my documentation practice.